Как запустить анализ метрик ПО в visual studio 2022
В общем у меня есть программа я её написать на языке с++ с использование winforms.
Но стандартным способом в visual нажимал Анализ -> выполнить code analysist и нажимал на запустить анализ кода своего проекта и так же нажимал решение не работает то есть пишет что там что-то собирается, но нечего не отображается в окне результат метрик кода, подскажите что не так делаю? весь основной код написан в myform.h.

Осознал что не корректно обратился за помощью, оказывается запуск анализа метрик ПО работает только в с#.

Запуск анализа метрик ПО работает только в с#
